# Preserving the current value of a local variable when there is recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion, multidimensional-array, nested

I'm writing a function to flatten a nested array (Python `list`). e.g turn [1,2,[3]] into [1,2,3], [[1,2,[3]],4] into [1,2,3,4] etc.

I have the following:

```
def flatten_array(array):
    flattened_array = []
    for item in array:
        if not isinstance(item, list):
            flattened_array.append(item)
        else:
            flatten_array(item)
    return flattened_array
```

So the idea is to have the function be recursive, to handle situations where there is nesting to an unknown depth. My problem is that `flattened_array` is getting re-initialized each time a nested list is encountered (when `flatten_array` is called recursively).

```
print flatten_array([1,2,[3]])
[1,2]
```

How can I maintain the state of `flattened_array` when recursive calls are made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the lines

```
else:
    flatten_array(item)
```

to

```
else:
    flattened_array+=flatten_array(item)
```

So the full function reads like

```
def flatten_array(array):
    flattened_array = []
    for item in array:
        if not isinstance(item, list):
            flattened_array.append(item)
        else:
            flattened_array+=flatten_array(item)
    return flattened_array
```

this gives

```
flatten_array([1,2,[3]]) # [1,2,3]
flatten_array([1,2,[3,[4,5]]]) # [1,2,3,4,5]
flatten_array([1,2,[3,[4,5]],6,7,[8]]) # [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Your original code is not doing anything with the recursive call.  You get back the result on the list, but just discard it.  What we want to do is attach it to the end of the existing list.

---

Additionally, if you don't want to keep creating temporary arrays, we can create one array with the first call to the function and just append to it.<sup>†</sup>

```
def flatten_array(array,flattened_array=None):
    if flattened_array is None:
        flattened_array = []
    for item in array:
        if not isinstance(item,list):
            flattened_array.append(item)
        else:
            flatten_array(item,flattened_array)
    return flattened_array
```

The results of this version are the same, and it can be used the same way, but in the original, each call to the function creates a new empty array to work with.  Normally this isn't a problem, but depending on the depth or how large the sub-arrays are this can build up in memory.

This version flattens the array into a given array.  When called with just the input (like `flatten_array([1,2,[3]])`), it creates an empty array to work with, otherwise it just adds to the given array (thus the recursive call just needs to give the array to add to), modifying it in place.

This has the advantage of allowing you to add to an existing array if we want:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,[4]] # we want to add flatten this to the end of a
flatten_array(b,a) # we don't bother catching the return result here
print(a) # [1,2,3,2,3,4]
```

---

<sup>**†**</sup> There is a subtle point here.  You may ask why we didn't define the function as `def flatten_array(array,flattened_array=[])` and get arid of the test inside the function.  Try that and call the function a few times.  What happens is that the default value is created once at function definition and not each time the function is called.  This means that the default array which is modified in place is shared by each function call, resulting in it accumulating the results.

This is likely not what we want.  By setting the default value to `None` and creating a new empty array inside the function each time, we ensure that each call to the function has a unique empty array to work with.

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't aware that the `+` operator could be used to append to a list.

Comment: @Pyderman It isn't exactly appending.  It merges the two lists together.  If you want to add an item to the list, you need to use the append method, but if you have two lists and you want to join one onto the end of the other, you can add them.  Note that, if you have studied much algebra, this is an example of non-commutative addition.

Comment: @Matthew Thanks for the additional elaboration, and for the alternate solution.